# Microstrategy - MSTR - Find the Lineage information from Table/Column to Report/Field

Tags: microstrategy

MSTR uses lots of components like attribute, metric, facts, Logical Tables etc to build a report. Is there any easy way to find the lineage information from Report to the actual Warehouse table ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to document the objects definitions?
If yes, you can use:[This](https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Architect/TN7853-How-does-the-Project-Documentation-Wizard-work-in/ta-p/168831)
you can document the objects forms, parents\childrens, components\dependencies and more...

If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the report in 'View SQL' mode from Developer tool. It will give information on the actual Warehouse tables used.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzGTL.png)

If you are run a report in Web, you can go to the Tools tab when the report data is displayed and click on Report Details Page option (bottom one), that will give you the sql.

Comment: Thanks But I need the full lineage information from Attribute to the Report Level